# Trying to compile phpredis for windows

Tags: php, windows, build, redis

I'm looking for a way to compile phpredis (https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis) for windows (because the few already compiled binaries I found where Thread Safe only thus not working on my NTS PHP). I've done everything written there : https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild but I'm clueless about what files/directories I should get from https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis, where to put them and how to have the building environment "configure" tool detect.
Note: I'm not familliar with Github as well.

Comment: See https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/213#issuecomment-11361242

Answer (score 0):

You can find the DLL's and intructions here:

http://char101.github.io/phpredis/

I just installed them successfully on my wamp server.

**UPDATE**

If that doesn't work, try to download from this link:
https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/downloads

(I was able to install on Windows 8/Wamp only with the second link)